# Multiple condition based http calls using axios in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to make get calls using axios (activeURl and inactiveURl). If there is an error message from get call of activeURl then check data with inactiveURl. Throw error message only if both url doesn't yield any data.
I should be getting data when making the nested call to inactiveURl but I am getting error messages all the time for inactiveURL.

```
axios({
        url: activeURl,
        method: "get",
    })
     .then(response => {
        res.status(200).json(response.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        axios({
            url: inactiveURl,
            method: "get",
        }).then(response => {
            console.log('INside thEN');
            res.status(200).json(response.data);
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: err
            });
        })
```

Comment: What is the error message from the `inactiveURL`?

Comment: The error message returned by the api call."No user found is the directory". I should be getting data instead of error message. I am getting the data when i call the inactiveurl with the queryparameters in browser.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you just try to call the api from some tools, such as Postman? And you still get the same result? If this is the case, it may be your api issue.

Comment: Yes I am sure. I used superagent npm package and used its callbacks to call inactiveurl if activeurl returns an error message and I am getting the data properly. I dont think we can nest another api call inside a catch block

Comment: Can you log the response in the inactiveUrl call's then? I think you are not getting "response.data" that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved. The call to inactive url should be in the then instead of catch block as the "Not Found" message is, I believe, also considered a valid response.

```
axios({
        url: activeURl,
        method: "get",
    })
     .then(response => {
        if(response.data !== "Not Found"){
        res.status(200).json(response.data);
}else{
axios({
            url: inactiveURl,
            method: "get",
        }).then(response => {
           
            res.status(200).json(response.data);
        })
}
    })
    .catch((err) => {
       
            res.status(500).json({
                message: err
            });
```